# Using an Enum and outputting it as a kendo dropdownlist

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

The dropdown expects

```
id: number
displayName: string
```

The enum looks like this:

```
export enum StatusEnum {
    Inactive = 0,
    Actice = 1,
    Completed = 2,
    NeedsAssistance = 3
}
```

The code to get the enum into a list looks like this:

```
StatusList = Object.entries(StatusEnum)
        .filter(([id, displayName]) => typeof displayName === 'string')
        .map(([id, displayName]) => ({ id, displayName }));
```

The problem is that the id is being set as a string and I can't convert it using parseInt or Number.

Hover on StatusList gives me this:
[image: The hover when I look at the StatusList]

Comment: Avoid using enum in typescript. It end up in final bundle size. 1 single enum take a lot of javsscript code.

Comment: Where you are getting the ID as string , In ngModel?

Comment: I think because its an enum its setting it as string. I need to convert it.